# Passing values from controller to controller in AngularJs using Factory

Tags: angularjs

I trying to pass a value from controller1 to controller2 using factory on ng-click, now i have added routing

```
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.router']);

  app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

$stateProvider
.state('ShowData', {
    url: '/ShowData',
    templateUrl: '../Pages/Show.html'
})
.state('EditData', {
    url: '/EditData',
    controller:'Editctrl',
    templateUrl: '../Pages/Edit.html'
})
    });

    app.controller('Controller1', function ($scope, $http, Phyfactory) {
    //Here I am calling a factory
    $scope.open = function (name) {

        var message = name;

        console.log('Hcpname', message);
        Phyfactory.set(message);
        $location.url('/EditData');

    // this is my second controller

    app.controller('Editctrl', function ($scope, Phyfactory) {
        alert('cntrl2');
$scope.fks = Phyfactory.get();
    });
```

I want to bind this value to textbox

```
    <div ng-controller="Controller2">
    Name: <input type="text" ng-model="fks" />
    </div>
```

//this is my factory

```
    app.factory("Phyfactory", function () {
      var phyname = {};

    function set(data) {
    phyname = data;
    alert('Inside set :' + phyname);
     }

function get() {
    alert('Inside get :' + Object.values(phyname));
    return phyname;
}
return {
    set: set,get:get
}

})
```

Adding HTML part for controller1 as requested, i am calling ng-click inside td

```
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="controller1"
    <table class="wtable">


        <tr>
            <th class="wth">
                A
            </th>
            <th class="wth">
                B
            </th>                
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="tab in Phyperform | filter:search.view_nm|filter:search.time_period|filter:search.team_nm">
            <td class="wtd" ><a ng-click="open(tab.A)"> {{tab.A}} </a> </td>
            <td class="wtd"> {{tab.B}} </td>                
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Value is not passing to `controller2` and not redirecting as well.

Any idea?

Comment: Please post HTML part of  Ctrl1

Comment: are you sure that the data from Html receives in Ctrl 1 and sets in Factory???

Comment: I edited with HTML part

Comment: @MohammadJavadSeyyedi Yes.. When I click A selected values getting populated(i tried putting an alert) basically its a string say "Mike Bostock" i am trying to pass.

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.href`

will redirect to out of the app, you must use routing with $location.

of course a better way to pass data between controllers is using event!

using event like below :

this is event receiver in controller 2:

```
$scope.$on('myCustomEvent', function (event, data) {
  console.log(data); // 'Data to send'
});
```

and this is the sender event in controller 1:

`$scope.$emit('myCustomEvent', 'Data to send');`

Comment: How would i do that using event please elaborate!!

Comment: This what i have done am i doing right?  app.controller('Controller1', function ($scope, $http, Phyfactory) {

//Here I am calling a factory
$scope.open = function (name) {

            var message = name;

            console.log('Hcpname', message);
            $scope.$emit('myCustomEvent', message);
            
});   app.controller('Controller2', function ($scope, Phyfactory) {
    alert('cntrl2');
    $scope.$on('myCustomEvent', function (event, data) {
        alert(data);
        console.log(data); // 'Data to send'
});

Comment: @PradeepKumar yep It's right, but if not working, try to use $rootScope in the receiver event instead of $scope!

Comment: both not working $scope & $rootscope, how it can be done with routing?

Comment: first of all learn about events, it's easy and ready to use, but if you want to use routing, use $location , first inject it to controller then $location.path('path to go')

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to this post "[Sharing Data between pages in AngularJS returning empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29448794/sharing-data-between-pages-in-angularjs-returning-empty)"

I able to do using sessionStorage.